# Where did Doc Hudson go?

Tags: cars, cars-2

Is it ever implied anywhere exactly what happened to Doc Hudson between the events of Cars and Cars 2? At I've point one of the characters says something like "doc would've been proud of you". I assume the reason for the character's exclusion is because Paul Newman didn't get signed up.

Comment: I think doc Hudson should show up in cars 3.

Comment: i wish that doc could stay alive with a and we will be happy that he did that he helped lighting mac quine and lighting mac quine was happy to have doc was there for him now lighting mac quine would not see doc anymore he was sad that doc was died before the other cars that were in a different country and cities that everyone was upset that doc was up in eve in

Answer (score 13):

[Paul Newman](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000056/) died in September 2008 and, although the pre-production on *Cars 2* was already in full swing, he was either too ill or already passed on before it came time to do the voice acting.

The scene you mention in your question is a touching homage to the legend that was Newman.

That said, it would have been nice if [George Carlin](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0137506/) (Fillmore) (and [Joe Ranft](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0710020/) (Red) for that matter) had been acknowledged in the same way instead of being replaced.

Comment: Joe Ranft was honored in the credits in the original *Cars* movie.  He died during production, ironically, in a car accident.

Comment: That's true - the montage they put together was quite touching. +1.

Answer (score 4):

In a [Time interview](http://entertainment.time.com/2011/06/22/a-qa-with-cars-2-director-john-lasseter/) with John Lasseter, he spoke about the reasons why Doc's voice wasn't recast;

> **Cars 2 includes an homage to Paul Newman, whose character, Doc Hudson, was the elder statesman of Radiator Springs. Newman died
> shortly after making the original Cars, and now the Piston Cup,
> McQueen’s big race, has been renamed the Hudson Hornet Piston Cup. Did
> you cast Michael Caine as Finn McMissile to try to fill those
> elder-statesman shoes?**
>
> *First of all, Paul Newman and I became very close friends. I loved that man. I went to a number of races with him and shared his love of
> racing. Every time I went to New York, I would have dinner with him
> and Joanne. **We have lost a few of our voice actors in the past and
> had to find soundalikes, but I just couldn’t do that because Doc
> Hudson was Paul Newman.***

[and](http://www.indielondon.co.uk/Film-Review/cars-2-john-lasseter-interview)

> So, that’s why I say he was Doc Hudson and Doc Hudson was him. So,
> when we started contemplating the new movie, right away we said:
> “Let’s just come up with a tasteful way to somehow pay homage to the
> character and to Paul Newman.” So, we came up with the idea that the
> big cup that they race for is called The Piston Cup, which became
> re-named The Hudson Hornet Memorial Piston Cup in honour of Doc Hudson
> and they turned his doctor’s office into a Doc Hudson Museum. So,
> there’s just a little moment with Mater and McQueen right at the
> beginning which was my kind of tribute to Paul Newman in the film.

That being said, I know of no source that confirms what the Doc actually died of *in-universe* (presumably simply of old age or the car equivalent of organ failure)

Comment: That actually raises a lot of questions. Can cars die? In the real world, people stop repairing cars once it gets two expensive, but theoretically you could just replace parts forever. It's not like humans where many parts don't have replacements and the components of all parts degrade over time. Where is a car's soul? If you replaced every part, would they still be them?

Comment: @vastra360 - They can [definitely die](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/scratchpad/images/7/75/Diecast_Leland_Turbo_Corpse.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120129081925).

Comment: WTF? Who would buy the corpse of a villain for their child? Anyway, the better phrasing is, can cars be immortal?

Comment: @vastra360 - Ask the question. I have answers

Comment: typo in Hudson Horney Memorial but edit is too short to be allowed.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - I've corrected it. Whichever nincompoop wrote this answer should be ashamed of himself... ;-)